# The ':make' command does not work in MacVim

Tags: vim, latex, macvim, tex

I have a Makefile for compiling a LaTeX project. When I run the command `:make` in the command line Vim, everything works fine. When I run it in the MacVim, I get the following:

```
:!make  2>&1| tee /var/folders/kh/jsj69y79239cfl3qb9108k400000gn/T/v4sX8Ac/0
pdflatex file.tex
make: pdflatex: No such file or directory
make: *** [file.pdf] Error 1
(1 of 3): pdflatex file.tex
```

The reason why I would like to possibly use it with MacVim is that I would like to use it in combination with Skim to be able to do forward-searching (i.e., I click in the pdf file and MacVim opens with cursor pointing at exactly that position).

Comment: Can we see the output of `:echo $PATH` in Vim *and* MacVim?

Comment: I see what you are trying to say. I did not think of this. Of course in MacVim I do not get the same results (I do not know how to copy them here). In MacVim there is much less and and for example in Vim there is '/Library/TeX/texbin', which I guess makes Vim recognize pdflatex.

Comment: One more thing. When I use backward-search in Skim (Command+Shift+Click), MacVim opens the .tex file with different value of $PATH than when I just open MacVim. So this might be causing the problem. When I open a file by backward-search I get wrong value of $PATH and `pdflatex` is not recognized.

Comment: Ok, I can confirm that if I open the MacVim, then open the file, everything is fine. So, for some reason if MacVim is not open and I just Command+Shift+Click in the pdf file this opens MacVim with wrong value of $PATH.

Comment: You should look into how exactly your PDF viewer's "Command+Shift+Click" is implemented and how it differs from how you open MacVim usually. Speaking of which… how do you start MacVim when everything works correctly?

Comment: Yes, this sounds like a way to go. Otherwise I start MacVim just by clicking on an icon.